# Bind static data as dictionary key

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

How to bind dictionary static data as dictionary key?

My XAML code:

```
<TextBlock
    x:Name="AxisXTextBlock"
    Width="37"
    Height="18"
    Margin="106,19,0,0"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    FontFamily="Source Code Pro"
    Text="{Binding DataStructure.DictionaryOfValuesReadOnly[AXIS_X].IntValue, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    TextWrapping="Wrap" />
```

Class of static data for keys of dictionaries:

```
public static class DataNames
{
    public static string SomeDataName { get; } = "some_data_name";
    ...
}
```

How can I bind `DataNames.SomeDataName` as a key of my dictionary in XAML code?

## UPDATE

I use dictionary converter and then bind it as StaticResource

```
xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:AppName.Converters"
...
<converters:SomeConverter x:Key="SomeConverter " />
...
Text="{Binding Path=DataStructure, Converter={StaticResource SomeConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static data:DataNames.SomeDataName}}"
```

Thanks [mm8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44112713/5651533) for helping in solution. His answer contains code for dictionary converter.

Comment: By the way, there is no point in setting `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `PropertyChanged` if your `Binding` is `OneWay` anyway.

Comment: @dymanoid Oh, it's a fair remark. I was copying TextBlocks in hurry and forget to change logic... Thank you for remark

Comment: I found a solution if you also need to have set compatiblity: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51750919/6229375

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid XAML doesn't support this kind of "dynamic" binding paths.

You could use a converter though, e.g.:

```
public class DictConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        IDictionary<string, string> dict = value as IDictionary<string, string>;
        string key = parameter as string;

        string s;
        if (dict != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(key) && dict.TryGetValue(key, out s))
            return s;

        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

---

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Dict, Converter={StaticResource conv}, ConverterParameter={x:Static local:DataNames.AxisX}}" />
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use static markup extension:

```
<TextBlock
    x:Name="AxisXTextBlock"
    Background="Yellow"
    Width="100"
    Height="30"
    Margin="106,19,0,0"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    FontFamily="Source Code Pro"
    Text="{Binding DataStructure.DictionaryOfValuesReadOnly[{x:Static local:DataNames.AxisX}].IntValue, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    TextWrapping="Wrap" />
```

Comment: That looks like a separate problem. What key value do you see in the debugger?