# Access dictionary value by key from XAML

Tags: c#, xaml

I am trying to access dictionary values by their key in XAML. I can do this with a string, but have no idea how to do this in XAML. Can someone point me in the right direction?

My class:

```
class Constants
{
    public static string testStr = "This is a test string";

    public static Dictionary<string, string> testDic;

    public Constants()
    {
        testDic = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        testDic.Add("KEY_Test1", "Test 1");
        testDic.Add("KEY_Test2", "Test 2");
        testDic.Add("KEY_Test3", "Test 3");
        testDic.Add("KEY_Test4", "Test 4");
    }
}
```

My xaml:

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Static local:Constants.testStr}"/> <!-- Works -->
<TextBlock Text="{x:Static local:Constants.testDic[KEY_Test3]}"/> <!-- doesn't work -->
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44111331/bind-static-data-as-dictionary-key

Comment: Thanks but I do not want to bind to the value. I did see that comment. I want to directly access it like I do with a static string.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to following and it will work.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=[KEY_Test3], Source={x:Static local:Constants.testDic}}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried @MilanG solution, It throwed errors, but it partially worked. I am not an expert and idk why this worked. I mean, it is almost the same thing right?

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding testDic[KEY_Test3], Source={x:Static local:Constants}}"/>
```

Comment: I think you just forgot to edit it for your own code

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30469999)